# split the content of a specific column with variable number of strings

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns, newlines

I need to print each "word" in the second column in a new line, copying the text in the first column in each new line. The columns are tab separated and all "words" in the second column start with "GO:" and are separated by a blank space. Also, there are different number of "words" in each line, from one to dozens.

For example

```
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1   GO:0003735 GO:0005783 GO:0005829  
TRINITY_DN6318_c1_g1_i1    GO:0004707 GO:0005524
```

Desired output

```
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1   GO:0003735
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1   GO:0005783
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1   GO:0005829
TRINITY_DN6318_c1_g1_i1    GO:0004707
TRINITY_DN6318_c1_g1_i1    GO:0005524
```

I have tried with awk

```
awk -v RS=" " '{print}' unique.ID_all.unique.GOs2
```

but what I got was

```
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1
GO:0003735
GO:0005783
GO:0005829
TRINITY_DN6318_c1_g1_i1
GO:0004707
GO:0005524
```

and I'm out of ideas. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

You could loop from 2 to the number of fields (`NF`) and print the first field and the other field separated by a tab:

```
awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1"\t"$i }' unique.ID_all.unique.GOs2
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), starting from

```
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1    GO:0003735  GO:0005783  GO:0005829  
TRINITY_DN6318_c1_g1_i1 GO:0004707  GO:0005524
```

and running

```
mlr --nidx --fs tab then reshape -r "^[^1]" -o item,value then cut -x -f item input.tsv >output.tsv
```

you will have

```
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1        GO:0003735
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1        GO:0005783
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1        GO:0005829
TRINITY_DN23871_c0_g1_i1
TRINITY_DN6318_c1_g1_i1 GO:0004707
TRINITY_DN6318_c1_g1_i1 GO:0005524
```

Some notes about the command:

- `--nidx --fs tab`, to set the input and output format
- `reshape -r "^[^1]" -o item,value`, to transform from wide to long the input file
- `cut -x -f item` to select the output columns